# iPad - Battery symbol on centre of screen

Tags: ipad

My iPad has died, all I've got is in the centre of the screen, when I touch on button, of an empty battery with a red line along the top, any ideas or is it a dead battery?

Answer (score 1):

The iPad battery has drained completely. Plug in the charger and wait for a few minutes for the iPad to turn on automatically.

If the iPad doesn’t turn on automatically, press and hold the power button after charging for 15 minutes to power it on.

To check if the battery is actually getting charged, plug in the charger, and press and hold the power button, the indicator on screen will show the device getting charged.

Comment: Also note that you must use the correct 10W or greater charger, not an iPhone charger as these won't always charge the device when it is extremely low on battery.